# Raising event in WPF

Tags: .net, wpf, routed-events

I'd like to raise a routed event in WPF manually.
So I called my control's `RaiseEvent` method.

My question is:
In this case, do I need to tunnel/bubble this event myself or WPF does it for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It'll do it automatically, so you don't have to worry about propagating it through the tree.